# My Django App can't connect to DB through a TypeError

Tags: python, django, django-database

My Django web application can't run because of a TypeError through my DB connection.

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 198, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

The error seems to happen when DB try to connect with connection parameters. Also, I'm trying to open my DB (sqlite) with credentials and connection was successful.

Other django commands like `python manage.py flush` didn't work through a DB connection can't be established.

`settings.py` file :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

My complete Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/flush.py", line 54, in handle
    allow_cascade=allow_cascade)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 15, in sql_flush
    tables = connection.introspection.django_table_names(only_existing=True, include_views=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 86, in django_table_names
    existing_tables = self.table_names(include_views=include_views)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/introspection.py", line 53, in table_names
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 198, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what about to show us your db settings?

Comment: @BearBrown just add my settings.py file database params

Comment: can you please show the result in the dajngo shell, `./manage.py shell` and then `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.DATABASES.get('default'))`

Comment: of course, super easy `{'PASSWORD': '', 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'TEST': {'MIRROR': None, 'CHARSET': None, 'NAME': None, 'COLLATION': None}, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'NAME': '/Users/[myusername]/PycharmProjects/[myproject]/db.sqlite3', 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'USER': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'TIME_ZONE': None}
`

Comment: did you changed your BASE_DIR path?? can you show that?

Comment: I did not. `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Comment: another thing, can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: and please add your django version, very strange python 3.4

Comment: I just add full traceback to my answer. It was impossible as a comment through a lot of characters. (Django version 2)

Comment: when are you getting this error?? means what command shows you this?

Comment: it can be django 2, looks to the source on git hub [dj2](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.0.x/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py#L198) but in [dj11](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py#L198) your case, try to reinstall django

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` and `python.manage.py flush` those two i tried to execute.

Comment: @BearBrown just reinstallation solves the problem. If you write it as answer i will accept as a correct one.

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos try to use Python3.6

Comment: glad to help you